# How to create LinkedIn follow button networkapicall url

Tags: objective-c, linkedin-api

How to create LinkedIn follow button networkapicall url,I have got the people/~/following/companies/ for first request, for second request i need the url for networkapicall.If anyone can give the url for networkapicall i will be thankful for them..

Answer (score 0):

you can get the link from :
     http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-plugin-generator

they give you the link for your profile URL

**Edit** :

Use `UIWebView`and give it the link as a`NSString`

Comment: I know that I have created a method and called followapi from my client code.. Then when i get response i have to parse the response and I have to call networkapi and the response should contain the share or follo count.. Please if anybody knows the full code reply me.Lots of thanks to the people replying me..